# react and passport missing token

Tags: reactjs, cookies, react-redux, passport.js, axios

I'm building a react app that communicates with another server using an API. The API call is using [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) but keeps failing on the passport authentication on the backend.
Using Postman the authentication it works fine with the react app the value of res.isAuthenticaded is false.
This is the value that arrives on the server using postman

```
[Node] req session--> Session {
[Node]   cookie: 
[Node]    { path: '/',
[Node]      _expires: null,
[Node]      originalMaxAge: null,
[Node]      httpOnly: true },
[Node]   passport: { user: '5a6a04f017589a97237dc9df' },
[Node]   returnTo: '/user/account' }
[Node] req session id--> a9uTD17j9fnPUYHd4srsfmvSfW6G3JZQ
[Node] isAuthenticated--> true
[Node] GET /user/account 200 210.616 ms - 54
```

And this is the value with the react app

```
Node] req session--> Session {
[Node]   cookie: 
[Node]    { path: '/',
[Node]      _expires: null,
[Node]      originalMaxAge: null,
[Node]      httpOnly: true },
[Node]   returnTo: '/user/account' }
[Node] req session id--> 2cWySg06ZZuozdS4nklfnd-8H5iPYDsC
[Node] isAuthenticated--> false
[Node] GET /user/account 403 56.948 ms - 28
```

[image]

Comment: Are you using session storage at all?  if not, it might solve your problem

Comment: Yes, my request does have the `Cookie` value but it seems that that way I send the server doesn't process it. Attached a print of my cookies

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the `axios` package does not send the headers back properly in order to work with `passport` because the `passport` token guard is looking for X-CSRF-TOKEN, but `axios` sends X-XSRF-TOKEN.
In order to solve my problem I change to this package to do my requests [whatwg-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/whatwg-fetch), works like a charm.
I hope this will help anyone with the same problem in the future.